# Pinecone upserting wrong values

Tags: python, machine-learning, vector, word-embedding, openai-api

I have the variable `meta` equal to the following list

```
[{'abstract': '  A fully differential calculation in perturbative quantum chromodynamics is\npresented for the production of massive photon pairs at hadron colliders. All\nnext-to-leading order perturbative contributions from quark-antiquark,\ngluon-(anti)quark, and gluon-gluon subprocesses are included, as well as\nall-orders resummation of initial-state gluon radiation valid at\nnext-to-next-to-leading logarithmic accuracy. The region of phase space is\nspecified in which the calculation is most reliable. Good agreement is\ndemonstrated with data from the Fermilab Tevatron, and predictions are made for\nmore detailed tests with CDF and DO data. Predictions are shown for\ndistributions of diphoton pairs produced at the energy of the Large Hadron\nCollider (LHC). Distributions of the diphoton pairs from the decay of a Higgs\nboson are contrasted with those produced from QCD processes at the LHC, showing\nthat enhanced sensitivity to the signal can be obtained with judicious\nselection of events.\n',
  'title': 'Calculation of prompt diphoton production cross sections at Tevatron and\n  LHC energies',
  'id_name': '0704.0001'},
 {'abstract': '  We describe a new algorithm, the $(k,\\ell)$-pebble game with colors, and use\nit obtain a characterization of the family of $(k,\\ell)$-sparse graphs and\nalgorithmic solutions to a family of problems concerning tree decompositions of\ngraphs. Special instances of sparse graphs appear in rigidity theory and have\nreceived increased attention in recent years. In particular, our colored\npebbles generalize and strengthen the previous results of Lee and Streinu and\ngive a new proof of the Tutte-Nash-Williams characterization of arboricity. We\nalso present a new decomposition that certifies sparsity based on the\n$(k,\\ell)$-pebble game with colors. Our work also exposes connections between\npebble game algorithms and previous sparse graph algorithms by Gabow, Gabow and\nWestermann and Hendrickson.\n',
  'title': 'Sparsity-certifying Graph Decompositions',
  'id_name': '0704.0002'}...,
```

```
for i in tqdm(range(0, len(arxiv_dataset['abstract']), batch_size)):
    # set end position of batch
    i_end = min(i+batch_size, len(arxiv_dataset['abstract']))
    # get batch of lines and IDs
    abstracts_batch = arxiv_dataset['abstract'][i: i+batch_size]
    titles_batch = arxiv_dataset['title'][i: i+batch_size]
    id_list = arxiv_dataset['id'][i: i+batch_size]
    print(id_list)

    ids_batch = [str(n) for n in range(i, i_end)]
    # create embeddings
    res = openai.Embedding.create(input=abstracts_batch, engine=MODEL)
    embeds = [record['embedding'] for record in res['data']]
    # prep metadata and upsert batch
    meta = [{'abstract': abstract, 'title': title, 'id_name': id_item} for abstract, title, id_item in zip(abstracts_batch, titles_batch, id_list)]
    
    to_upsert = zip(ids_batch, embeds, meta)
    # upsert to Pinecone
    index.upsert(vectors=list(to_upsert))
```

I'm using tqdm to batch data and then upsert to pinecone. However, when upserting, pinecone butchers the id_name and sets it to some datetime format. Thus, when I query back, I'm not getting the id_names of each of the results. I'm instead getting a value like  `'id_name': datetime.date(704, 4, 26)`

How do I fix it so that data remains same while upserting and I get that value back when querying?